# How to get rid of trailing slashes and make a redirect to homepage in nuxt.js

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, trailing-slash

When I’m trying to open site with trailing slashes (example.com///) in the end I’m getting an error in the console, but I want to make redirect to example.com/

[image]

It's in my nuxt.js project which I deployed to Google App Engine. I searched and tried a lot but nothing helped.

Anyone knows how I can achieve this in nuxt.js or maybe I can do it in Google App Engine?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code? Where you use the this `replaceState` ?

Comment: @vitooh Hi, I'm not using this method in my code it's from nuxt.js

Comment: ok, I understand  - it seems that that's an issue in the routes
can you share the app.yaml?